# Title text not showing in Win32 application written in Rust

Tags: winapi, rust

After following the [Opening a Win32 Window](https://rust-tutorials.github.io/triangle-from-scratch/opening_a_window/win32.html) tutorial, when I use the `cargo run` command, it shows a window that does not have a title.

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
#[link(name = "Kernel32")]
extern "system" {
    pub fn GetModuleHandleW(lpModuleName: LPCWSTR) -> HMODULE;
}

#[link(name = "User32")]
extern "system" {
    pub fn RegisterClassW(lpWndClass: *const WNDCLASSW) -> ATOM;
    pub fn GetLastError() -> DWORD;
    pub fn CreateWindowExW(
        dwExStyle: DWORD,
        lpClassName: LPCWSTR,
        lpWindowName: LPCWSTR,
        dwStyle: DWORD,
        X: c_int,
        Y: c_int,
        nWidth: c_int,
        nHeight: c_int,
        hWndParent: HWND,
        hMenu: HMENU,
        hInstance: HINSTANCE,
        lpParam: LPVOID,
    ) -> HWND;
    pub fn ShowWindow(hWnd: HWND, nCmdShow: c_int) -> BOOL;
    pub fn DefWindowProcW(hWnd: HWND, Msg: UINT, wParam: WPARAM, lParam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT;
    pub fn PostQuitMessage(nExitCode: c_int);
    pub fn DestroyWindow(hWnd: HWND) -> BOOL;
    pub fn GetMessageW(
        lpMsg: *mut MSG,
        hWnd: HWND,
        wMsgFilterMin: UINT,
        wMsgFilterMax: UINT,
    ) -> BOOL;
    pub fn TranslateMessage(lpMsg: *const MSG) -> BOOL;
    pub fn DispatchMessageW(lpMsg: *const MSG) -> LRESULT;
    pub fn UpdateWindow(hWnd: HWND) -> BOOL;
}

pub type c_int = i32;
pub type c_uint = u32;
pub type HANDLE = PVOID;
pub type HBRUSH = HANDLE;
pub type HCURSOR = HICON;
pub type HICON = HANDLE;
pub type HINSTANCE = HANDLE;
pub type HWND = HANDLE;
pub type LONG_PTR = isize;
pub type LPARAM = LONG_PTR;
pub type LPCWSTR = *const WCHAR;
pub type LRESULT = LONG_PTR;
pub type PVOID = *mut core::ffi::c_void;
pub type UINT = c_uint;
pub type UINT_PTR = usize;
pub type WCHAR = wchar_t;
pub type wchar_t = u16;
pub type WPARAM = UINT_PTR;
pub type HMODULE = HINSTANCE;
pub type ATOM = WORD;
pub type WORD = c_ushort;
pub type c_ushort = u16;
pub type DWORD = u32;
pub type HMENU = HANDLE;
pub type LPVOID = *mut core::ffi::c_void;
pub type BOOL = c_int;
pub type LONG = c_long;
pub type c_long = i32;

pub type WNDPROC = Option<
    unsafe extern "system" fn(hwnd: HWND, uMsg: UINT, wParam: WPARAM, lParam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT,
>;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct WNDCLASSW {
    pub style: UINT,
    pub lpfnWndProc: WNDPROC,
    pub cbClsExtra: c_int,
    pub cbWndExtra: c_int,
    pub hInstance: HINSTANCE,
    pub hIcon: HICON,
    pub hCursor: HCURSOR,
    pub hbrBackground: HBRUSH,
    pub lpszMenuName: LPCWSTR,
    pub lpszClassName: LPCWSTR,
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct MSG {
    pub hwnd: HWND,
    pub message: UINT,
    pub wParam: WPARAM,
    pub lParam: LPARAM,
    pub time: DWORD,
    pub pt: POINT,
    pub lPrivate: DWORD,
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct POINT {
    pub x: LONG,
    pub y: LONG,
}

impl Default for MSG {
    #[inline]
    #[must_use]
    fn default() -> Self {
        unsafe { core::mem::zeroed() }
    }
}

impl Default for WNDCLASSW {
    #[inline]
    #[must_use]
    fn default() -> Self {
        unsafe { core::mem::zeroed() }
    }
}

pub fn wide_null(s: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    s.encode_utf16().chain(Some(0)).collect()
}

const WS_OVERLAPPED: u32 = 0x00000000;
const WS_CAPTION: u32 = 0x00C00000;
const WS_SYSMENU: u32 = 0x00080000;
const WS_THICKFRAME: u32 = 0x00040000;
const WS_MINIMIZEBOX: u32 = 0x00020000;
const WS_MAXIMIZEBOX: u32 = 0x00010000;
const WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: u32 =
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;
const CW_USEDEFAULT: c_int = 0x80000000_u32 as c_int;
const SW_SHOW: i32 = 5;

const WM_NCCREATE: u32 = 0x0081;
const WM_DESTROY: u32 = 0x0002;
const WM_CLOSE: u32 = 0x0010;

extern "system" fn window_proc(hwnd: HWND, uMsg: UINT, wParam: WPARAM, lParam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
    unsafe {
        match uMsg {
            WM_NCCREATE => {
                return 1;
            }
            WM_DESTROY => {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            }
            WM_CLOSE => {
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                return 0;
            }
            _ => {
                return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let hInstance = unsafe { GetModuleHandleW(core::ptr::null()) };
    let sample_window_class_wn = wide_null("Sample window class");

    let mut wc = WNDCLASSW::default();
    wc.lpfnWndProc = Some(window_proc);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = sample_window_class_wn.as_ptr();

    unsafe {
        if RegisterClassW(&wc) == 0 {
            println!(
                "Not able to register window class. Error code: {}",
                GetLastError()
            );
        }
    }
    let sample_window_name_wn = wide_null("sample window");
    let hwnd = unsafe {
        CreateWindowExW(
            0,
            sample_window_class_wn.as_ptr(),
            sample_window_name_wn.as_ptr(),
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            core::ptr::null_mut(),
            core::ptr::null_mut(),
            hInstance,
            core::ptr::null_mut(),
        )
    };
    unsafe {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    }
    unsafe {
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    }

    let mut msg = MSG::default();

    unsafe {
        while GetMessageW(&mut msg, hwnd, 0, 0) > 0 {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Find the sections of code where yours deviates from the tutorial's. For one, your call to `GetMessageW` shouldn't be filtering on a window handle. Why did you change that?

Comment: Didn't realize that, some sort of mistake, but it still does not work

Comment: So then, find the other places you changed without realizing that you changed things. Since you have followed a tutorial that recommends using *cargo* to create a crate, you already have a Git repository. Git is suited to quickly find changes.

Comment: Well that is the problem, I looked at this code and I couldtn find anything wrong

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the handling of `WM_NCCREATE`. The MSDN documentation is not very clear about this, but this message is used so that the window class is able to filter and/or modify the creation parameters of the window. These parameters are received in the `lParam` argument that is actually a `CREATESTRUCT*`.

The idea is that you do the cast with `CREATESTRUCT *cs = (CREATESTRUCT *)lParam;`, then you inspect and/or modify the contents of that struct and finally you pass on the message to `DefWindowProc()` to continue creation or `return 0` to abort.

But it looks like the linked tutorial is doing `return 1` *without* forwarding it to `DefWindowProc()`. Just don't do that: most messages should be forwarded to `DefWindowProc()` except those you *know* you should not.

In your particular example, you can remove the `return 1` from the `WM_NCCREATE` branch and move the `DefWindowProc()` call to outside of the match:

```rust
    match uMsg {
        WM_NCCREATE => {
            //...
            //no return
        }
        WM_DESTROY => {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        WM_CLOSE => {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            return 0;
        }
        _ => {}
    }
    DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)
```

NOTE: Although the Windows source code is not (yet) publicly available, the next best thing is the source code of Wine. You can check what `DefWindowProc(WM_NCCREATE)` does [here](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/e909986e6ea5ecd49b2b847f321ad89b2ae4f6f1/dlls/user32/defwnd.c#L976):

```
    case WM_NCCREATE:
        if (lParam)
        {
            CREATESTRUCTW *cs = (CREATESTRUCTW *)lParam;

            DEFWND_SetTextW( hwnd, cs->lpszName );
            result = 1;

            if(cs->style & (WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL))
            {
                SCROLLINFO si = {sizeof si, SIF_ALL, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0};
                SetScrollInfo( hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si, FALSE );
                SetScrollInfo( hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, FALSE );
            }
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved it, I had a suspicion that it had something to do with nccreate but didn't know what to do.

Comment: I looked at msdn and it said to return 1 if I wanted to continue the creation of my window

Comment: @taste01: Yes, this doc is misleading because it assumes that `DefWndProc()` does nothing useful. The thing is that `DefWndProc(WM_NCCREATE)` returns 1, so doing a chain-return `return DefWndProc(...)` is the proper way to go on. The thing is that to manage the window creation you should generally use `WM_CREATE`, not `WM_NCCREATE`, the `WM_NC*` messages are somewhat advanced and the docs assume you already know what you are doing.

Comment: The tutorial handles `WM_NCCREATE` to attach a state object to the window. This is in preparation of allowing a window procedure to access window-local state.